# Pipeline Docker-Jenkins-Jmeter

Tags: docker, jenkins, jmeter

I am trying to configure the Pipeline Docker-Jenkins-Jmeter
**Expected result**: take test plans from my computer, run them on Jmeter with the help of Jenkins using docker container

Below I will write what I've done and a question

1. I downloaded Jenkins image on Docker, created the container and configured it.
2. In Jenkins I downloaded plugins: performance plugin (for Jmeter)
3. Then I create Freestyle project and add data [image]

**Build action**
C:\Users\Aliaksandra\Desktop\JMETER\apache-jmeter-5.4.1_old\apache-jmeter-5.4.1\bin>jmeter
jmeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml -n -t C:\Users\Aliaksandra\Desktop\JMETER\apache-jmeter-5.4.1_old\apache-jmeter-5.4.1\bin\R.jmx -l C:\Users\Aliaksandra\Desktop\JMETER\apache-jmeter-5.4.1_old\apache-jmeter-5.4.1\bin\R_result_report.jtl

the code above perfectly runs from my cmd command line on Windows but in Jenkins no with this error
[image]

**Post-build action**
C:\Users\Aliaksandra\Desktop\JMETER\apache-jmeter-5.4.1_old\apache-jmeter-5.4.1\bin\R_result_report.jtl

As I understand, my Jenkins image cannot run my test plan because it doesn't have Jmeter installed?? Do I need (or is it possible) to install Jmeter with the help of command line CLI on Jenkins container  OR   do I need to Install the second container Jmeter? I am stuck.

P.S. I have Jmeter on my Windows computer and from command line everything perfectly runs

Answer (score 0):

1. Looking at `/var/jenkins_home....` path you're seem to be using default [Linux containers](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/#switch-between-windows-and-linux-containers) therefore you need to change your Windows paths `c:\users\aliaksandra....` to their Linux equivalents.
2. We don't know where you "downloaded the Jenkins image" from and how exactly you have "configured" it but my expectation is that the Jenkins image won't contain JMeter installation and you will have to [download and install JMeter there](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-get-started-jmeter-installation-test-plans) (either in the image or in the container). In case of building the image from the [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) you will need to add a couple of lines there, something like:

   ```
   ARG JMETER_VERSION=5.4.3

   RUN mkdir -p /jmeter \
       && cd /jmeter \
       && wget -q https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-${JMETER_VERSION}.tgz \
       && tar -xzf apache-jmeter-${JMETER_VERSION}.tgz \
       && rm apache-jmeter-${JMETER_VERSION}.tgz
   ```
3. As the continuation of the point 1 you will need to switch to "Execute shell" build step and re-configure it as:

   [image]

   alternatively you can use [Docker Volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) so the container would use JMeter installation and the test plan from the host, but I'm not 100% sure this is something you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I downloaded Jenkins image from dockerhub using command docker: docker pull jenkins/jenkins. And run using this comment: docker run --name MyJenkins3 -p 7070:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v C:/Users/Aliaksandra/Documents/Jenkins_admin_r:/var/jenkins_home jenkins/jenkins. I couldnt find on the Internet how to download from the linux command line jmeter/ I have linux version on my Jenkins CLI: https://prnt.sc/26guhq3

Comment: I understood that I need to download  Jmeter on My Jenkins container but the commands I used for linux do not work

Comment: Error when I install Jmeter on my Lenkins image